# Window.open issue in firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am opening a new window on clicking a hyper link.

Issue:
After minimizing the window, again if I click on hyper link, the same window should be opened(In chrome minimized window will open up). But this is not happening in firefox and IE. Can anyone please help.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" onclick="window.open('http://www.w3schools.com/html/', 'newwindow', 'width=1500, height=900'); return false;">Visit our HTML tutorial</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tested here, and it's working on both Firefox and Internet Explorer for me.

Answer (score 0):

window.open allows you to specify a unique identifier to your popup; this allows you to open many links always in the same popup window.
If you use different identifiers on different links, it should open multiple popup windows.

```
<p>
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" onclick="window.open('http://www.w3schools.com/html/', 'newwindow', 'UNIQUEID', 'width=1500, height=900'); return false;">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
</p>

<p>
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/" onclick="window.open('http://www.w3schools.com/html/', 'newwindow', 'ANOTHER_UNIQUEID', 'width=1500, height=900'); return false;">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If the strWindowFeatures parameter is used and no size features are defined, then the new window dimensions will be the same as the dimensions of the most recently rendered window.

you might want to check this link
[window.open web api for mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Unique ID in the parameter's list simply doesn't work as suggested in another answer.

You need a function for to do what you need in IE and FF. The trick is to get a function to see if it has opened a window before and do nothing if it has.

```
<script>

            var opened = false;          

            function openWindow(){          

                if (!opened) {

                    w = window.open('', 'test', 'width=1500, height=900');                    
                    w.location = "http://www.google.com";;

                    w.onload = function() {
                        w.onunload = function() {
                            opened = false;
                        };
                    };
                    opened = true;
                }

            }

</script>
```

I'm using the `opened` global variable to track this. We set the newly created window to set `false` to this variable when it closes. Now the function can decide if it should really open a new window. Please note the following points:

1. We use onLoad function of the new window to set onUnload. Because IE seems to replace whatever the event handlers set here soon after it loads the page.
2. You can see that we first open a blank window and then set the url of it. This is because IE returns nothing when opening a new window if it is from another domain.